# Get column table from database and show the data by array to right side in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, foreach, html-table

Please help.

i have one table like this

```
sn     | date      | status    | 
001    | 2017-01-01| work      | 
001    | 2017-01-02| work      | 
001    | 2017-01-03| work      |
001    | 2017-01-04| work      |
002    | 2017-01-01| sick      |
002    | 2017-01-02| sick      |
002    | 2017-01-03| sick      |
002    | 2017-01-04| sick      |
003    | 2017-01-01| work      |
003    | 2017-01-02| work      |
003    | 2017-01-03| work      |
003    | 2017-01-04| work      |
```

i want to show the table to my view like this

```html
<table border="1">
    <tr>
    <td>sn</td>
    <td>01</td>
    <td>02</td>
    <td>03</td>
    <td>04</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>001</td>
    <td>work</td>
    <td>work</td>
    <td>work</td>
    <td>work</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>002</td>
    <td>sick</td>
    <td>sick</td>
    <td>sick</td>
    <td>sick</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>003</td>
    <td>work</td>
    <td>work</td>
    <td>work</td>
    <td>work</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

how to write code models and controller for this case. very confused for this case.

i just create models like this

```
function attendance()
    {
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('mytable');;
        $query=$this->db->get();
        return $query;
    }
```

and my controller like this

```
function get_attendance()
    { $this->m_human_capital->attendance()->result();
        $this->template->display('myview',$data);
    }
```

thank you so much for the answer.

Comment: Have you googled for tutorials on how to do it?

Comment: i'm not sure what keyword for this case. can you give me referense?

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/codeigniter/ and https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/codeigniter-tutorial#Step-4-8211-Creating-Simple-App-with-CodeIgniter should help

Comment: i can get data but just array at view same table in database. @Sunil

Comment: i have edit my question @Sunil

Comment: @Mardino Ismail please can you check this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: No one who want to help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update

New method works if you have some `people` or `sn`s that don't have data for a particular day if they were sick or working. If this is the case, shows X.

*Also consider ordering by date in your model!*

Controller:

```
function get_attendance() {
    $rows = $this->m_human_capital->attendance()->result_array();
    $dates = array();
    $identifiers = array();
    $people = array();
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        if (empty($row['date']) || empty($row['sn'])) {
            continue; // no date or sn, nothing to print for this row...
        }
        // in array assures unique values
        if (!in_array($row['date'], $dates)) {
            $dates[] = $row['date'];
        }
        if (!in_array($row['sn'], $identifiers)) {
            $identifiers[] = $row['sn'];
        }
        // this may seem convoluted, take your time to understand
        $people[$row['date']][$row['sn']] = $row;
    }
    $data = array(
        'people' => $people,
        'identifiers' => $identifiers,
        'dates' => $dates,
        'title' => 'sometitle' // or...
    );
    // ... $data['tite'] = 'sometitle';
    $this->template->display('myview', $data);
}
```

View:

```
<table border='1'>
    <tr>
        <th>sn</th>
        <?php
        foreach ($dates as $date) {
            echo "<th>{$date}</th>";
        }
        ?>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach ($identifiers as $id) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $id; ?></td>
            <?php
            foreach ($dates as $date) {
                echo '<td>';
                if (isset($people[$date][$id]['date']) && $people[$date][$id]['date'] == $date) {
                    echo $people[$date][$id]['status'];
                } else {
                    echo 'x';
                }
                echo '</td>';
            }
            ?>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</table>
```

---

### Original Solution

Only handles "homogeneous" inputs as your example has, where dates all line up, and there is data for every person or `sn` for every day on whether they were at work or sick.

Do the following in your controller as you aren't passing the data properly:

```
function get_attendance() {
    $rows = $this->m_human_capital->attendance()->result_array();
    $data = array();
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        $data[$row['sn']][] = $row;
    }
    $this->load->helper('somehelper'); // name of helper where you put the function below.
    $dates = unique_multidim_array($rows, 'date');
    $view = array(
      'rows' => $data,
      'dates' => $dates,
      'title' => 'sometitle'
    );
    $this->template->display('myview', $view);
}
```

Store this function in a helper and load it:

```
<?php
function unique_multidim_array($array, $key) {
    $temp_array = array();
    $i = 0;
    $key_array = array();

    foreach ($array as $val) {
        if (!in_array($val[$key], $key_array)) {
            $key_array[$i] = $val[$key];
            $temp_array[$i] = $val;
        }
        $i++;
    }
    return $temp_array;
}
?>
```

Then in your view:

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>sn</th>
        <?php foreach ($dates as $row): ?>
            <th><?php echo $row['date']; ?></th>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tr>
    <?php
    foreach ($rows as $i => $j):
        echo "<tr><td>$i</td>";
        foreach ($j as $v):
            ?>
            <td><?php echo $v['status']; ?></td>
            <?php
        endforeach;
        echo '</tr>';
    endforeach;
    ?>
</table>
```

The problem you will face is that if the table doesn't look exactly like above you might get weird results. The issue here is that tables are generated procedurally via foreach and then adds rows. We don't know which column each status per user will land in as we have to have *already* generated the date column.